# what does it mean to reject a hypothesis?

Tags: self-learning, absolute-value

This is a simple problem I cannot understand. The task is to solve:

> $$\frac{2}{3} \times |5-2x| - \frac{1}{2} = 5$$

1. As a first step, I isolate the absolute value, like this:

\begin{align} 
    2/3 \times |5-2x| &= 5 + 1/2\\ 
    2/3 \times |5-2x| &= 11/2\\ 
          |5-2x| &= 11/2 ÷ 2/3 \\
          |5-2x| &= 33/4\\   
          |5-2x| &= 8.25
\end{align}
2. Now, $|5-2x|$ can be two things:
$$
|5-2x| =\begin{cases} 5-2x     & x \geq 2.5\\
5+2x & x < 2.5.    
\end{cases}
$$

3. Let's solve the equation $|5-2x| = 8.25$

if $x \geq 2.5$, then:
\begin{align}
    5-2x &= 8.25\\
     -2x &= 3.25\\
       x &= -1.625
\end{align}
But we said that $x \geq 2.5$!

I get a similar contradiction if I calculte the other conditional: $x < 2.5$
\begin{align}
    -5+2x &= 8.25\\
       2x &= 13.25\\
        x &= 6.625
\end{align}
which is not smaller than $2.5$.

As far as I know, in such situations, we tend "reject the solution." But what does it mean for a solution not to confirm to a hypothesis?

(The problem is from Stitz & Zeager (2013) Precalculus, exercise: 2.2.1/8.
I apologise for not being able to use nice formatting.)

Comment: Why do you say $|5-2x|=5-2x$ when $x\ge 2.5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$5-2x\ge 0\iff |5-2x|=5-2x$$ but $$5-2x\ge0\iff 2x\le 5,$$

unlike what you wrote.

In this particular exercise, no hypothesis is rejected, so it doesn't illustrate the concept.

Comment: I didn't know that multiplying an inequality by -1 changes the direction of the inequality sign. Thank you so much for pointing that out, Yves! Also, please, let me know if I should edit or do something with the post, because (I realise) it's really not a question about hypothesis rejection. Thank you.

Comment: @malasi: I did'nt work this out with a multiplication but by changing members.

Comment: what do you mean by "changing members?" I'm confused now.

Comment: I got it, you simply added +2x to the inequality 5-2x ≥ 0. I had somehow gotten confused by the order of members. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said, note that we can solve the equation by noting that 
$$
|x|=a\iff x=\pm a
$$
In particular 
$$
|5-2x|=8.25\iff 5-2x=8.25 \quad \text{or} \quad 5-2x=-8.25
$$
which is perhaps easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to solve this kind of equation is consider **two cases**

**1)** For $5-2x\ge 0 \iff x\le \frac25$ we have

$$\frac23 |5-2x| - 1/2 = 5 \iff \frac23 (5-2x) - 1/2 = 5 \iff 20-8x-3=30 \\\iff 8x=-13 \iff x=-\frac{13}8$$

that solution is acceptable since it is consistent to the assumption $x\le \frac25$.

**2)** For $5-2x< 0 \iff x> \frac25$ we have

$$\frac23 |5-2x| - 1/2 = 5 \iff \frac23 (2x-5) - 1/2 = 5 \iff 8x-20-3=30 \\\iff 8x=53 \iff x=\frac{53}8$$

which is also acceptable.

As an example with some solution to reject refer to [Why am I getting a wrong answer on solving $|x-1|+|x-2|=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2861379/505767).